# Форматирование чисел в JS. 01 вместо 1

Tags: javascript, форматирование

Нужна помощь, в cursera задание по js, нужно чтобы выводилось корректное время, при добавлении интервала.

```
module.exports = function(hours, minutes, interval) {
  if (hours >= 0, hours <= 23,
    minutes >= 0, minutes <= 59) {
    if (minutes + interval >= 60) {
      hours = hours + 1;
      minutes = (minutes +
        interval - 60)
    } else {
      minutes = minutes + interval
    };
    if (minutes.length = 1) {
      miutes = '0' + minutes
    };
    return hours + ':' + minutes
  } else {};
};
```

Суть в том, что я не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы вместо 1, на вывод приходило 01. На сайте была подсказка:

Для выполнения этого задания могут понадобиться методы глобального объекта Math. Например, метод floor.

Comment: если интервал это минуты, то я бы на вашем месте все что есть привел к минутам, а потом отделил часы.

Comment: подождите, и это единственная проблема? все остальное работает?

Comment: `return ('00' + hours).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + minutes).slice(-2);`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Такой контент принято писать в ответ

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych для чего такие изощрения? Ведь есть готовая функция padStart

Comment: @EgorRandomize ответ дан в 2018 году, тогда я только начинал учить js )

Answer (score 3):

`String.prototype.padStart()` заполняет текущую строку другой сторокой (несколько раз, если нужно) так, что итоговая строка достигает заданной длины. Заполнение осуществляется в начале (слева) текущей строки.

Вот готовая функция:

```
function padNum(var num) {
    return num.toString().padStart(2,0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать такую функцию:

```
function MakeTwoDigits(num) {
  if( num >= 0 && num <= 9) {
    return "0" + num;
  }
  else { 
    return "" + num;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log([0, 1, 9, 10, 59].map(x => ("0"+x).slice(-2)).join(" "))
```